# Solaris 10: x11-server does not show up as a service

Tags: solaris, x11, solaris-10

I have a Solaris 10 box I recently put the latest recommended patch set on.  X is running, along with cde-login.  When I do a "svcs" I can see the cde-login service, but x11-server does not show up as a service, even if I do a "svcs -a".  In the process list, X shows up as:

/usr/openwin/bin/Xsun :0 -defdepth 24 -nobanner -auth /var/dt/blah

x11-server is not listed in inetadm, so I don't think it's being run legacy style.

How is X getting started if it's not being run by SMF?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you disable the cde-login service? I would expect that X is actually started by the cde-login service itself.

Comment: I think you might be right, but on other servers I actually see x11-server as a separate service.  I ended up solving my problem by switching to gdm as the display manager (instead of cde-login) which seems to behave much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a pstree (or equivalent) to see what started it.  That might help.

Answer (score 0):

X is started by either dtlogin or gdm, which run the /usr/X11/bin/Xserver script that reads the properties from the x11-server SMF service to determine which X server to start (Xsun or Xorg) and what flags to start it with.   `x11-server` only shows up in the `svcs -a` output if an instance has been created to start it up directly, instead of via the display manager - that may be done for machines running a kiosk-type service that don't want the login screen from the display manager, or machines running Xvfb for web services to use for rendering images, etc.